# pthread_key_t and pthread_once_t?

Tags: c++, pthreads, unix

Starting with pthreads, I cannot understand what is the business with pthread_key_t  and pthread_once_t?

Would someone explain in simple terms with examples, if possible?

thanks

Comment: For newcomers, I suggest reading Chapter *31: Threads: Thread Safety and Per-Thread Storage* of the *The Linux Programming Interface* book, you will get all your answers there. You won't understand the rationale behind these variables before knowing the `thread<->function<->key<->thread specific data` model.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, it can't be explained in layman terms. Laymen cannot successfully program with pthreads in C++. It takes a specialist known as a "computer programmer" :-)

`pthread_once_t` is a little bit of storage which `pthread_once` must access in order to ensure that it does what it says on the tin. Each once control will allow an init routine to be called once, and once only, no matter how many times it is called from how many threads, possibly concurrently. Normally you use a different once control for each object you're planning to initialise on demand in a thread-safe way. You can think of it in effect as an integer which is accessed atomically as a flag whether a thread has been selected to do the init. But since `pthread_once` is blocking, I guess there's allowed to be a bit more to it than that if the implementation can cram in a synchronisation primitive too (the only time I ever implemented `pthread_once`, I couldn't, so the once control took any of 3 states (start, initialising, finished). But then I couldn't change the kernel. Unusual situation).

`pthread_key_t` is like an index for accessing thread-local storage. You can think of each thread as having a map from keys to values. When you add a new entry to TLS, `pthread_key_create` chooses a key for it and writes that key into the location you specify. You then use that key from any thread, whenever you want to set or retrieve the value of that TLS item for the current thread. The reason TLS gives you a key instead of letting you choose one, is so that unrelated libraries can use TLS, without having to co-operate to avoid both using the same value and trashing each others' TLS data. The pthread library might for example keep a global counter, and assign key 0 for the first time `pthread_key_create` is called, 1 for the second, and so on.

Comment: Doesn't explain in "layman" term, Adam's answer is short and to the point.

Answer (score 14):

`pthread_key_t` is for creating thread [thread-local storage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-local_storage): each thread gets its own copy of a data variable, instead of all threads sharing a global (or function-static, class-static) variable.  The TLS is indexed by a key.  See [`pthread_getspecific`](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/man/pthread_getspecific.txt) et al for more details.

`pthread_once_t` is a control for executing a function only once with [`pthread_once`](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/man/pthread_once.txt).  Suppose you have to call an initialization routine, but you must only call that routine once.  Furthermore, the point at which you must call it is after you've already started up multiple threads.  One way to do this would be to use `pthread_once()`, which guarantees that your routine will only be called once, no matter how many threads try to call it at once, so long as you use the same control variable in each call.  It's often easier to use `pthread_once()` than it is to use other alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

Wow, the other answers here are way too verbose.

`pthread_once_t` stores state for `pthread_once()`. Calling `pthread_once(&s, fn)` calls `fn` and sets the value pointed to by `s` to record the fact it has been executed. All subsequent calls to `pthread_once()` are noops. The name should become obvious now.

`pthread_once_t` should be initialized to `PTHREAD_ONCE_INIT`.